# replace WinSCP with FileZilla - is this possible?

Tags: linux, ssh, key, filezilla, winscp

well i am a admirer of the superb WinSCP (see http://winscp.net ) FTP-client for many years. Several months i switched to Linux - now i run a OpenSuse 11.4.

Question - can i replace WinSCP with FileZilla - is this possible

Well i did not yet got started with and adequate GUI-alternative that replaces WinSCP.
In fact - WinSCP is one of the main reason i still have a windows box here in my office!
Question: are there any alternatives for WinSCP on OpenSuse 11.4 - perhaps filezilla?

Another question: can i port over the keys from WinSCP to Filezilla - is this possible!? Is it difficult!?

look forward to hear from you

Comment: I'm 99% sure OpenSUSE has a GUI SCP/SFTP client built right into the file manager. It probably already supports everything you want, too, since your requests are pretty normal. I do all of this in Ubuntu, at least.

Comment: If you will need to import WinScp into FileZilla, use : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632313/export-sessions-from-winscp-to-filezilla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileZilla, in my opinion, is the best (S)FTP client. After WinSCP that is. Using WinSCP on my job just because it has SCP support. Don't know of any other GUI tool which has SCP support, both on Windows an Unix/Linux OS.

Also, as far as I know there is no method for importing public SSH key in FileZilla (http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto).

Comment: hello hrle - thx for your answer! That means i cannot use FileZilla to replace WinSCP!?  Did i get you right!?

Comment: well - what bout putty - does putty replace the WinSCP?  Love to hear from you

Comment: You can replace WinSCP. FileZilla supports SSH key authentication. But, you can not export your WINSCP servers settings and import it into FileZilla.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood your question so forgive me. Also, I didn't use FileZilla for a while now, but as I can remember - it doesn't support password protected private key files. But hey, other than that and lack support for SCP it is really great peace of software. It is also cross platform.

Comment: many many thanks - i also installed putty - and i give both a try!

Comment: Also, PuTTY is a SSH and Telnet client. It is not an FTP client. Maybe you meant PSFTP. This is also from the same developer as PuTTY. PSFTP _is_ SFTP client. But PSFTP is not available for Linux like PuTTY. So again, long story short - the only real alternative to WinSCP on Linux is FileZilla. I really hope that someone else with greater experience would post here another name for (S)FTP client.

Comment: A serious problem with Filezilla is that it will not attempts to reconnect in case of timeout. But by default WinSCP supports it.