# Export (migrate) sessions from WinSCP and import into FileZilla

Tags: import, export, filezilla, winscp

I have been using WinSCP for a while and have decided to give FileZilla another go for a while before I make the final decision.

Is there a way to export all my saved sessions from WinSCP and import them into FileZilla?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FileZilla does not support any kind of import from other applications.

Writing a script to convert WinSCP INI configuration file to FileZilla XML configuration file should not be that difficult. If it's worth the effort, depends on how many sessions you have. Converting passwords encrypted by WinSCP to an unencrypted (or base64-encoded) form that FileZilla uses would be the most challenging (if you save passwords).

Note, that once you realize that WinSCP is better and you decide to switch back, you can easily import your new FileZilla sessions to WinSCP:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import

Comment: Would love a MacoS version of WinSCP. The only reason I have bootcamp running is WinSCP.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no linux version of WinSCP.

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a neat little program available that read and converted WinSCP.ini files to a sitemanager.xml file, which could then be imported by FileZilla.

I used it in the past with some success, as I remember. However, I can't find my copy now.  I think it was thread in a thread in which Martin was either the OP or a contributor, where I found it.

The only thing I can find now is [WinSCPSiteConfigurationToFileZilla](https://github.com/Mikaciu/WinSCPSiteConfigurationToFileZilla) which a small PHP script that is supposed to convert the WinSCP sites to FileZilla format. The PHP page outputs an upload form, with which you can upload your WinSCP.ini file and the script is supposed to allow you to download the matching sitemanager.xml file, but it doesn't seem to work now.

This is a shame because I now find I really need it. I am sure it would be super simple for someone like Martin to build script/program that would help us users who have Windows machines at home, but use Linux [Ubuntu] at work and need to have access to the same remote servers from both.

That would be great, of course, but the best thing he could do for us would look something like this...

`apt get install LinSCP`

;-)

Comment: Or Maybe a MonoSCP ;-) That would be great too.